# Nested __try...__except clauses, how does this work?

Tags: c++, try-catch, seh

I'm dealing with a function and a subfunction, the subfunction being called within the function. Both have a `__try .. __except`-clause, and I'd like to see the general exception handling in case of the function, and the specific one in case of the subfunction, in other words:

```
int function(){
__try{
  do_something();
  return subfunction();
  } __except (Exception_Execute_Handler_Something()){
  show("general exception");
  }

int subfunction(){
  __try{
    return do_something_else();
  } __except (Exception_Execute_Handler_Something_Else()){
    show("specific case");
  }
```

In this case:
When `do_something()` goes wrong, I see "general exception".
When `do_something_else()` goes wrong, I also see "general exception", which is not what I want.

What I want is:
When `do_something()` goes wrong, I want to see "general exception.
When `do_something_else()` goes wrong, I want to see "specific case".

**Edit after Ben Voight's remark**

There indeed is an exception filter, and this is currently checking the exception code for deciding whether or not to continue, as you can see here:

```
if (Exception->ExceptionCode == STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION)
  return EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_SEARCH;
```

I have, however, no knowledge at all in the structure and/or content of `ExceptionRecord` and `ContextRecord`, the two input parameters of the exception handling. Hereby I give an example of what those parameters look like in my particular case:

Exception record:

```
-   ExceptionRecord 0x0eecdec8 {ExceptionCode=3221225620 ExceptionFlags=0 ExceptionRecord=0x00000000 <NULL> ...}    _EXCEPTION_RECORD *
    ExceptionCode   3221225620  unsigned long // I guess this means division by zero
    ExceptionFlags  0   unsigned long
+   ExceptionRecord 0x00000000 <NULL>   _EXCEPTION_RECORD *
    ExceptionAddress    0x002c1993 {<Application>.exe!CClass::Main_Method(CInputClass & params), Line 46}   void *
    NumberParameters    0   unsigned long
+   ExceptionInformation    0x0eecdedc {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}    unsigned long[15]
```

ContextRecord:

```
-   ContextRecord   0x0eecdf18 {ContextFlags=65543 Dr0=0 Dr1=0 ...} _CONTEXT *
    ContextFlags    65543   unsigned long
    Dr0 0   unsigned long
    Dr1 0   unsigned long
    Dr2 0   unsigned long
    Dr3 0   unsigned long
    Dr6 0   unsigned long
    Dr7 0   unsigned long
-   FloatSave   {ControlWord=0 StatusWord=0 TagWord=0 ...}  _FLOATING_SAVE_AREA
    ControlWord 0   unsigned long
    StatusWord  0   unsigned long
    TagWord 0   unsigned long
    ErrorOffset 0   unsigned long
    ErrorSelector   0   unsigned long
    DataOffset  0   unsigned long
    DataSelector    0   unsigned long
+   RegisterArea    0x0eecdf50 ""   unsigned char[80] // all are zero
    Spare0  0   unsigned long
    SegGs   43  unsigned long
    SegFs   83  unsigned long
    SegEs   43  unsigned long
    SegDs   43  unsigned long
    Edi 80923496    unsigned long
    Esi 250405956   unsigned long
    Ebx 0   unsigned long
    Edx 0   unsigned long
    Ecx 0   unsigned long
    Eax 1   unsigned long
    Ebp 250405884   unsigned long
    Eip 2890131 unsigned long
    SegCs   35  unsigned long
    EFlags  66118   unsigned long
    Esp 250405880   unsigned long
    SegSs   43  unsigned long
+   ExtendedRegisters   0x0eecdfe4 "\x2 \x1"    unsigned char[512] // at first sight, not readable
```

Now my question has turned into:

In case I'm already inside another `__try..__except` clause, I'd `return EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_SEARCH`.

Does anybody know which of the mentioned `ExceptionRecord` or `ContextRecord` properties I can use for determining whether or not I am already inside another `__try..__except` clause?

**New edit after again some more information**

I've just found `EXCEPTION_DISPOSITION`, present in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include\excpt.h`. This contains the function `_except_handler()`, which returns an `EXCEPTION_DISPOSITION` enum, which can be `ExceptionNestedException` (I believe this is the one I'm looking for).
So now the question turns into:

> What parameters do I need to fill in in the function `_except_handler()` in order to know if I'm dealing with a nested exception (or does somebody know an easier way to get this done)?

Comment: What is `__try` `__except` ? that's obviously no standard c++ code.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ `__try`/`__except` is Microsoft specific

Comment: @Ayxan Well, I know that already. I just wanted to nudge the OP tagging and explaining their question better about that thing specifically.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Sorry, I had no idea __try __except clauses not being general C++. I've added the "SEH" tag accordingly.

Comment: Does it work to```int temp = subfunction(); return temp;```

Comment: Where are your exception filters?  Those are what give you the power to keep searching for a handler or not.

Comment: @Dominique: Since you were not aware that SEH is not standard C++, I think it's fair to ask if you have considered using [standard C++ exceptions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/exceptions)? (Even [Microsoft recommends ISO-standard C++ exception handling instead of SEH in C++](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/structured-exception-handling-c-cpp?view=vs-2019).) If you really want SEH, that's fine; my intent is to make sure you are aware of the alternative, to make sure this is the question you want to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code as written does not compile.  Instead of:

```
__except { ... }
```

you need:

```
__except (EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER) { ... }
```

Then it works as desired.

[Live demo](https://rextester.com/ZOXL14311)

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

int do_something_else()
{
    *(reinterpret_cast<int*>(0)) = 1;
    return 0;
}

int do_something()
{
    return 0;
}

int subfunction();

int32_t ReportCrash(LPEXCEPTION_POINTERS ExceptionInfo) //exception and context pointers are hrere
{
    return EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER;
}

int function()
{
    __try 
    {
        do_something();
        return subfunction();
    }
    __except (ReportCrash(GetExceptionInformation()))
    {
        std::cout << ("general exception");
    }
    return 0;
}

int subfunction()
{
    __try 
    {
        return do_something_else();
    }
    __except (ReportCrash(GetExceptionInformation()))
    {
        std::cout << ("specific case");
    }
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n"; 

    function();
}
```

The details are [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/debug/structured-exception-handling)

Answer (score 1):

You can use RaiseException.

```
#define SUBCODE 0x1000

int Filter(LPEXCEPTION_POINTERS exceptionPointers,DWORD& code) {
  code = exceptionPointers->ExceptionRecord->ExceptionCode;
  return EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER;
}

int function(){
  DWORD code;
  __try{
      do_something();
      return subfunction();
    } __except ( Filter( GetExceptionInformation(), code )  ){  
      if (code == SUBCODE) {
        show("specific case");      
      } else {
        show("generic code");
      }
    }
}

int subfunction(){
  __try{
    return do_something_else();
  } __except (EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER){
    RaiseException( SUBCODE , 0, 0 , NULL );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`EXCEPTION_RECORD`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/ns-winnt-exception_record) structure has a member called `ExceptionRecord` which is a pointer to another `EXCEPTION_RECORD` ...

This is how you tell if you have nested exceptions.